# What is more meaningful in causal inference - magnitude of coefs or information criterion?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, regression-coefficients, lasso, causality

I have 100+ variables with 2000+ observations. I am trying to pick most important variables to put it into casusal inference models and get insight into the "true" process. I am aware of the implications of limited *a priori* information about the underlying process - I might not generate the "true" model. My response is a type of indicator placed on a continuous scale $[0,1].$ I came up with this approach:

1) Conditional decision trees - efficient and simple interpretation, but has a problem with "kicking out" correlated but still meaningful variables when comparing to the other methods importances of variables.

2) Adaptive LASSO - same problem as above.

3) GAMs - with all variables, select=TRUE and method="REML" and that's it, then I check the significant smooth terms, unfortunately it shrinks linear relations.

4) Linear/beta regressions - iteratively building models for each IV and stacking them to check magnitude or AIC. Unfortunately some of variables are giving better fit, some bigger magnitude.

So I am stuck with the fourth option. The greater share of variables is on the same scale. What should be more meaningful in casual inference?  Size of the coefficients, lowest significance or information criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information criterion (AIC, BIC, etc.) are equivalent to an adjusted RSquare measure simply penalizing the Goodness-of-fit of the whole model for the number of variables used.  They won't give you information at the variable level.

Given that I would eliminate the information criterion to evaluate specific variables.  But, I would keep those to evaluate competing models.  This is just like R Square is important to know how much a model explain of the variance of Y.  But, R Square does not tell you much if anything at the variable level.

What I would do to ensure that your variables are truly on the same scale is to standardize them.  And, rerun your models.  Once you do that I bet that the standardized coefficient (higher ones) will be 100% convergent with the higher t-stats (higher), and the resulting p-values (lower).  I just can't think how you could possibly have variables with higher standardized coefficients and lower t-stats and higher p-values.  Mathematically, I don't know that this is possible.

Higher standardized coefficients, higher t-stats, lower-p values will all tell you in a convergent ways which ones of your variables are more influential.

However, this does not mean that those variable selections are correct despite the favorable and supportive statistical testing framework.  You always have to select your variables in a way that supports the underlying supporting logic of what you are testing.  You can have a variable that is very statistically significant, but if it has the wrong directional sign, you obviously have to remove it from your model.  If the direction does not make sense, your model does not make sense.  That's actually the main consideration in your variable selection process.

Comment: Thank you for the exhausting response. Regarding to the coefficients relations with stats I'm embarassed, you're right and that suppose to be clear foundation to me.